# count qty in checked row and update div element

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jquery-selectors

[image]

I made a div to display counted qty (Total)

```
<div style='font-size:18px;'>Total : <div id='total_qty_chk' style='display:none' value=''></div> </div>
```

And I made a jquery to count every checked checkbox in any row,

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

var total_qty_chkd = document.getElementbyId('#total_qty_chk'); //display count
total_qty_chkd.value = 0;
var chkqty1 = document.getElementsByClassName('txtbtsclass'); //qty value saved here


    $("input:checkbox").on("change", function () { //when clicked

        $.each($("input[id='chkajax']:checked"), function(){    //count every clicked checkbox        
            Number(total_qty_chkd.value) = Number(total_qty_chkd.value) + Number(chkqty1.value);
        });
        total_qty_chkd.toggle();

    });


});
```

For Example when I clicked the first and the second checkbox, Total will show value **36.8**

Can someone help me solve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`closest()` and `find()` are your friend to get value.

```js
$("input:checkbox").on("change", function() {
  var sum = 0;
  $.each($("input[class='chkajax']:checked"), function() {
    sum += Number($(this).closest('tr').find('td:last').text());
  });
  $('#total_qty_chk').toggle($(".chkajax:checked").length > 0 );
  $('#total_qty_chk').text(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkajax"></td>
    <td>o5242</td>
    <td>14</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkajax"></td>
    <td>o5245</td>
    <td>22.8</td>
  </tr>

</table>
<div style='font-size:18px;'>Total :
  <div id='total_qty_chk' style='display:none' value=''></div>
</div>
```

*Note: 1. You are not providing any html so I assume it's a table. Same thing apply on div too.* 
*2. ID must be unique so use class instead of id*.

Comment: does last in find means it will select the last td in row?

Comment: Yep that is. You can also find with class , id whatever you want.

Comment: what could I do if I want to select a specific td value? like select by index?

Comment: `find('td').eq(index)`  index for  0, 1, 2 whatever your desire :)

Comment: Alternative: `.find('td:eq(index)');`

Comment: I searched, and I choose 'td:nth-child(3)' . But still, you made my day sir.. Thanks a lot :)